# Nondimensionalization of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to reduce the number of parameters of the following ODE:
$$u'=ku+ruln(u)$$ where k, r are parameters.
When solving similar problems, we've used techniques like substitution. For example:
$$u'(x)=ku(x)$$ Let$$ y=kx$$ $$ w(y)=u(x)$$ Then $$w'(y)=(u(\frac{y}{k}))'$$ $$w'(y)=\frac{1}{k}ku((\frac{y}{k}))$$ $$w'=w$$
And we got rid of parameter k.
However, the problem with the first eq. is that we have log, which basically ''switches multiplication to addition''. To illustrate what I mean, here's my attempt:
$$\pi=kt$$ $$w(\pi)=u(t)=u(\frac{\pi}{k})$$ $$w'(\pi)=(u(\frac{\pi}{k}))'$$ $$w'(\pi)=\frac{1}{k}u'(\frac{\pi}{k})$$ $$w'(\pi)=\frac{1}{k}(ku(\frac{\pi}{k})+ru(\frac{\pi}{k})ln(u(\frac{\pi}{k})))$$ $$w'(\pi)=w(\pi)+\frac{r}{k}w(\pi)lnw(\pi)$$
So we kind of got rid of the parameter in front of the first term, but if we try to use substition as $z=Cw$ where C is some konstant, log will turn it to logC + logW which isn't very useful. I tried something like $z=e^\frac{r}{k}w$:
$$z'=e^\frac{r}{k}w'$$ $$z'=z+\frac{r}{k}zln(e^\frac{k}{r}z)$$ $$z'=z(1+1+\frac{r}{k}ln(z))$$
Also, I've forgot to mention: ODE with a given inital condition $u(0)=u_0$

Answer (score 1):

$$u'=ku+ru\ln(u)$$
$v(x)=\ln(u)$
$$e^v v'=ke^v+re^vv$$
$$v'=k+rv$$
This is a first order linear ODE that you can solve.

ADDITION in order to answer to your comment :

The aim of the change of function $v(x)=\ln(u)$ is to simplify the equation. This is the first step to remove the parameters $k$ and $r$ which is possible for the linear equation :
$$v'=k+rv$$
Let $v=k\,w$
$$\frac{dw}{dx}=1+r\,w$$
Let $x=\frac{t}{r}$
$$r\frac{dw}{dt}=1+r\,w$$
Let $z=r\,w$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=1+z$$
This is the first order linear ODE without parameter in it.

Comment: I just want to be sure we're on the same page. My question was related to nondimensionalization, how to ''remove'' the parameters. The problem isn't solving this ODE, it's simplifying it. From what you have written I've got: $z=\frac{k}{r}+v$, $z'=v'$, $z'=r(\frac{k}{r}+v)$, $z'=rz$ and then for $\pi=rt$  and $y(\pi)=z(t)$, $y'(\pi)=(z(\frac{\pi}{r}))'$, $y'=y$. Is this what you've meant? It's much different from initial eq., but is it the same? How to interpret this for our model? From what I can see: $v(0)=log(u_0)$, $z(0)=\frac{k}{r}+v(0)$ , we \log'd our data and then added a constant?

Comment: My answer was the first step to nondimensionalization. I thought that you knew how to remove the parameters from a first order linear ODE. See the addition to my main answer.